# Visibility of activityIndicator isn't changed after changing the value of variable which is bind with animating props

Tags: react-native, activity-indicator

I need to show the loading indicator while data is fetching from server. For this purpose I added

```
<View>
          <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.isLoading} size="large" color="#0000ff" />
        </View>
```

Here's the place where I call fetching function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.state.isLoading = true;
    const { getCities } = this.props;
    getCities();
    this.state.isLoading = false;
  }
```

So, I wanted to show loading indicator in this place (as I change the variable, which influences on visibility of loading indicator) but unfortunately nothing happens. So, what's the reason and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing buzzles me :
- it isn't a good practice to set state synchronously, you should use the setState function

I would refactor as follows:

```js
displayLoading = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
}

closeLoading = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
}

fetchCities = async () => {
    const { getCities } = this.props;
    displayLoading()
    await getCities()
    closeLoading()
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchCities()
}
```

NB: for this solution, I consider that you do not use/need redux :) otherwise, i would suggest redux and a middleware to automate the display loading to all api fetch

Comment: Solved my issue, thank you. I'm new to React - what's the difference between this.setState({ isLoading: false }) and this.state.isLoading= false? Presumably setState tells React to re-render whereas this.state.isLoading = false doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

`View` does not have a style specified.

```js
this.state={
  isLoading : true
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { getCities } = this.props;
    setTimeout(() => {
    getCities();
    this.setState({isLoading: false})
     }, 5000)
  }

....
render() {
    return this.state.isLoading === true ? (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator
          size="large"
          color="#0000ff"
        />
      </View>
    ) : (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      ...
```

Comment: unfortunately it also doesn't help. animating in render is only false

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii I updated my answer. This way you'll certainly see the indicator for five seconds.

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii If your problem is solved, could you choose my answer?